# Battleship python, taking turns resets the board

Tags: python, loops, return

I'm making a battleship game, and everything works fine. But since I've included a turn system the game doesn't work as it should. The game has two boards (one hidden, the other is 'public' the one which opponents can see (so no ships). The hidden works, but the public resets every turn, so you can't see what was your previous hit.

The code below is for the 'attack' sequence, and of-course the while loop for turns.
So what do you advice to properly implement the turn system? I just need to get the information about the 'public' board out of the function.

```
    def napad(osebni_board):

    board = [] #this is the public board, the 'private' one is defined in another function (the board is called osebni_board)
    for x in range(0,5):
        board.append([" "] * 5)
    x=0
    while x<1 :
        napad_vrstica=streljaj_vrstica()
        napad_stolpec = streljaj_stolpec()
        osebni_board_priverjanje = list(itertools.chain(*osebni_board))

        if napad_vrstica <= len(board)-1 and napad_stolpec <= len(board[0])-1 and "S"  in osebni_board_priverjanje:
            print osebni_board_priverjanje
            if  osebni_board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]=="S":
                osebni_board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]="" #osebnemu boardu se element S spremeni v element H, zato, da ponovni stren ni razumljen kot zadetek
                board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]="H"
                osebni_board_priverjanje = list(itertools.chain(*osebni_board))

                print True
                print "Kapitan, vase koordinate so se izkazale za tocne. Sovrazna ladja je uspesno potopljena!"
                print_board(board)
                if "S" not in osebni_board_priverjanje:
                    print_board(board)
                    print "game over"
                    break

            elif board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]=="H":
                print "Ladja na koordinatah {},{} je ze bila potopljena, kapitan {}!".format(napad_vrstica, napad_stolpec, ime)



            elif osebni_board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]=="M":
                print "Na koordinate {},{} ste ze streljali, kapitan {}!".format(napad_vrstica, napad_stolpec, ime)



            else:
                board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]="M"
                osebni_board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]="M"
                print "Zadetek neuspesen, kapitan {}!\n".format(ime)
                print_board(board)

        else:
            mrtvi = random.randint(100, 10000)
            print "Kapitan! Zadeli smo obalo! {} mrtvih!\nPoskusite znova!".format(mrtvi)
        x+=1

    return osebni_board_priverjanje
```

turns system:

```
igralec = 0
while True:
    if igralec%2==0:
        print "Na vrsti je igralec 1"
        napad_igralec_1=napad(igralec_2)

    else:
        print "Na vrsti je igralec 2"
        napad_gralec_2=napad(igralec_1)
    igralec+=1
    print igralec
```

Comment: Could you perhaps try translating the variable names to English?

Comment: That is interesting: reading code in another language ... but English would help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure because I can't understand the variable names, but at the beginning of your `napad` function, you set `board = []`, so that will erase whatever was in `board`.  Also it looks like `board` is a local variable, so no matter what you do it will disappear every time the function ends.  If I understand your code right, it seems as if you are loading the private board into the public board every time you call `napad`, but if every time you do this you start with `board = []`, then the public board will have no persistent state.  When you do things like `board[napad_vrstica][napad_stolpec]="M"`, you are just setting an element in the local variable `board`, which is thrown away when the `napad` function ends.  To fix all this, you would need to create the public board once, outside the `napad` function, initialize it with blanks, and then reference that public board (as a global variable or by passing it in as an argument) from within your `napad` function.

Comment: Instead of referencing it as global variable I'd say to pass the board around as second parameter to `napad`.

Comment: but if I put board as a second parameter, what should I write as a second parameter in the turn while loop?

plus I tried to make board =[] outside the napad.... it is persistant, but there's only one instance of it. so both attacks are shown on one board instead on two different public ones...